# Ionic 2: Unable to create table TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am trying to open a database and create a table in my Ionic 2 app.
The following method is part of a service and is supposed to open the db and create the table:

```
initDb() {
    let db = new SQLite();
    db.openDatabase({
        name: "data.db",
        location: "default"
    }).then(() => {
        db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (avatarUrl VARCHAR, firstName VARCHAR, lastName VARCHAR)", []).then((data) => {
            console.log("Table created: ", data);

        }, (error) => {
            console.error("Unable to create table", error);

        })
    }, (error) => {

        console.error("Unable to open database", error);
    });
  }
```

The method is called in my home page's constructor:

```
constructor(public platform: Platform, public navCtrl: NavController,  public dbService: DBService) {
     this.platform.ready().then(() => {
       this.dbService.initDb();
     });
  }
```

I have no idea why I am getting this error (refer to the title).
Thanks

Comment: Have you already tried to wrap your initDb method with a setTimeout and give it a 1sec delay? Because when using crosswalk the ready method might be fired too early, as it states [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/issues/882)

Comment: It removed the `Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined error`, thanks! But now I cannot call any method (from the service or even local ones) inside the setTimeout method, I am getting `'this.function' is not a function` for local methods and `Cannot read property 'initDb' of undefined` for initDb.

Comment: Actually I could not access my methods because I was using `setTimeout(function() {})` which caused context issues.
When using `setTimeout(() => {})`, I am still getting the `Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined` error.

Comment: Ok, as far as I googled this myself some function/s is not called by ionic-scope instance itself, so its still a kind of context problem. If I were you I would replace all arrow functions () => {} with anonym functions function(){}

Comment: Did so in home.ts and in my service, still the same errors. I also tried this: `setTimeout(function() {this.dbService.initDb();}.bind(this),1000)` and I'm getting a new similar error: `Cannot read property 'dbService' of null`

Comment: Can you assign this to a variable(var instance) before calling ready, then call instance.dbService.initDb() within ready.

Comment: Getting `Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined` again ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I could not reproduce this error but build a testapp on my own. This app works with me, despite *this* is called within *ready* as well:

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen, SQLite } from 'ionic-native';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { DbService } from '../providers/db-service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers: [DbService]
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = TabsPage;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public dbService: DbService) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
      this.dbService.initDb();
    });
  }
}
```

I made this service by using this ionic-command:

```
ionic g provider DbService
```

db-service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { SQLite } from 'ionic-native';

/*
  Generated class for the DbService provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class DbService {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello DbService Provider');
  }

  initDb() {
    let db = new SQLite();
    db.openDatabase({
      name: "data.db",
      location: "default"
    }).then(() => {
      db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (avatarUrl VARCHAR, firstName VARCHAR, lastName VARCHAR)", []).then((data) => {
        console.log("Table created: ", data);

      }, (error) => {
        console.error("Unable to create table", error);

      })
    }, (error) => {

      console.error("Unable to open database", error);
    });
  }

}
```

ionic-version: 2.1.18

cordova-version 6.0.0

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well i've started a new clean project just like you did and it works. I have no idea what's wrong with the other one though...
Thanks A LOT for your time!

Comment: You are welcome! It was my pleasure. :) There is a Happy End, nothing else matters.